# Best practices in notation

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, notation, article-writing

I have already read *A Primer of Mathematical Writing*, by Steven Krantz which gives extremely good advice about writing mathematics. But I would like to collect some more specific suggestion about notation. I know that there are many different possible and equally correct notations and that it is a matter of taste and that therefore this question is likely to be very subjective. However, I am sure that there are some choices that are agreeably better than others.

To make only an example, I personally feel that ":" is preferable to "|" to express "such that", because "|" is used to mean "divisible" as well, and that $\mathbb{N}_0$ is neater than $\mathbb{N}^{>0}$.

So my question is: can you point out some "officially recognized"choices of notation that are agreeably better than other ones in terms of clarity? Even better, can you recommend some **references** on this topic?

Comment: To me $\mathbb N_0$ contains $\{0\}$.

Comment: @GitGud really? How would you indicate $\mathbb{N}^{>0}$ then?

Comment: @GitGud well, I think it depends on the authors anyway.

Comment: Yes. That's how I learned in school and it stuck so hard that it seems completely natural to me. Also $\mathbb N^{>0}$ I denote simply by $\mathbb N$, though I confess that $\mathbb N_{>0}$ seems much more common (than $\mathbb N^{>0}$) to me. And yes, it depends. I'm just saying to me it is like that, it's not universal, I believe.

Comment: As for $\color{blue}\colon$ over $\color{blue}\mid$, I agree. However divisibility is not part of everyday life for everyone, so I can see why it wouldn't be a problem. I still prefer $\color{blue}\colon$ over $\color{blue}\mid$ because I've never seen any case in which $\colon$ could be ambiguous.

Comment: I much prefer $\mathbb Z^+$ over $\mathbb N^{>0}$, because the latter looks clunky to me.  As for the meaning of the symbol $\mathbb N$ on its own, I doubt that we're ever going to reach a consensus on whether $\mathbb N$ contains zero or not. Each author has to make that choice (and say explicitly what it is!) based on context.

Comment: $\mathbb N^\star$. It makes no sense for $\mathbb N$ to exclude $0$, since then it would lack the neutral element for addition, and it would not be able to form a group with it, and a ring with multiplication, as opposed to all others: $\mathbb Z$, $\mathbb Q$, $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb A$, $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Lucian, I don't think that's the main reason $\mathbf{N}$ has come to include zero. There used to be debate about whether zero actually existed as a number, as many felt it was as artificial as a negative number. Set theory provides an obvious criterion: natural numbers are those that correspond to the cardinalities of sets, and the empty set is a set. However, from a naive perspective, zero feels artificial, which is why the traditional view is still strong at the school level. I do think there is a consensus now among mathematicians that $0 \in \mathbf{N}$, just not in teaching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good resource is Florian Cajori's [A History of Mathematical Notation](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486677664), which will at the least give you a glimpse of the sheer variety of ways of notating things.  Volume I is [available online](https://archive.org/details/historyofmathema031756mbp).

**Added later**: My looking up Cajori's book on Amazon prompted Amazon's recommendation engine to tell me about [*Mathematical Notation: A Guide for Engineers and Scientists*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1466230525) by Scheinerman$^2$.  (It also reminded me of another very nice book on the history of notation:  [*Enlightening Symbols*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0691154635) by Joseph Mazur.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't necessarily believe that these sources are better, but I can try to answer your question about what's "official."

1. ISO, the International Organization for Standardization, has an official set of mathematical symbols. See http://www.ise.ncsu.edu/jwilson/files/mathsigns.pdf . I believe they may have had physicists in mind more than mathematicians, but that's what there is.
2. Bourbaki's notations are of course hugely influential. And the more time you've spent in France, the more likely you are to think of them as "official." They are responsible for the hilarious $\subsetneq$, and I believe they may also be the reason mathematicians in France and some other countries began referring to the number $0$ as "positive" (as well as "negative").

Comment: $>$ is "**strictly** greater than", as opposed to $\ge$, which is "greater or equal than". In like manner, $>0$ is "**strictly** positive", as opposed to $\ge0$, which is "positive". Likewise, $<$ is "**strictly** lesser than", as opposed to $\le$, which is "lesser or equal than". In like manner, $<0$ is "**strictly** negative", as opposed to $\le0$, which is "negative". Equally, we speak of "**strictly** increasing/decreasing/monotonous", as opposed to "increasing/decreasing/monotonous", etc. Conceptual uniformity is key to a clearer thinking.

Comment: Yes, I understand the underlying reasoning. It was felt that $\leq$ was a more important relation than $<$, and should therefore have the simpler terminology associated with it. The difficulty with this is that you can't turn the entire language on its head lightly.